# Plotting multiple files on same graph

Tags: gnuplot, tcpdump, tcptrace

I need to plot the outputs of various xpl files generated by tcptrace on the same graph so that graphical comparison becomes easier. Note: Here the x-axis is common for all xpl files(time). Only the y-axis differs. I need something like 2 y axis. One on left one on right.

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example of how to set multiple axes [here](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/multiaxis.html).

Comment: I had seen that before but how to plot tcptrace output that way(xpl files). Also when xpl files are plotted using jPlot we can magnify the graph and observe it in depth. Can that be done?

Comment: @user1761399 -- That depends critically on what terminal driver you're using.  Terminals like `wxt` support mousing.  You can click-drag a box on the plot to zoom in to that portion for example.